# Make EJB timer not re-execute if a runtime exception occurs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, transactions, ejb

Suppose we have this class:

```
@Startup
@Singleton(mappedName = "workflow", name = "workflow")
@ConcurrencyManagement(value = ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class Workflow implements WorkflowInterfaceLocal, WorkflowInterfaceRemote {
    private Object msg;

    public <T> Future<Object> doTask(T msg) {
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if(i==5) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("a");
                }
                System.out.println("DOTASK" + (i+1));
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                //e
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTimer(long intervalDuration) {
        LOG.debug("Setting a programmatic timeout for " + intervalDuration
                + " milliseconds from now.");

        timerService.createTimer(intervalDuration, null);
    }

    @Timeout
    private void executeOnTimeout(Timer t){
        LOG.debug("start -  doTask with timer timeout");
        t.cancel(); //execute one time and cancel the timer
        doTask(this.msg);
        LOG.debug("end - doTask with timer timeout");

    }
}
```

This class is supposed to call `executeOnTimeout` asynchronously, which will call the `doTask` method.

This is how I call it:

```
WorkflowInterfaceRemote workflow = lookupRemoteEJB(WorkflowInterfaceRemote.class);
workflow.setTimer(0);
```

It works, the method gets called succesfully, and the caller method does not hang, so the `@Timeout` annotated method is getting called asynchronously.

Maybe you noted the `RuntimeException` in the `doTask` method. I put it there for a specific reason: If the `doTask` fires (for whatever reason) a `RuntimeException`, the EJB container relaunches it, so the output is:

```
[01/12/14 11.49.27:258 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK1
[01/12/14 11.49.28:258 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK2
[01/12/14 11.49.29:258 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK3
[01/12/14 11.49.30:259 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK4
[01/12/14 11.49.31:259 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK5
[01/12/14 11.49.38:274 CET] 00000017 LocalExceptio E [Exception stack trace]

[01/12/14 11.49.33:272 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK1
[01/12/14 11.49.34:273 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK2
[01/12/14 11.49.35:273 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK3
[01/12/14 11.49.36:274 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK4
[01/12/14 11.49.37:274 CET] 00000017 SystemOut     O DOTASK5
[01/12/14 11.49.38:274 CET] 00000017 LocalExceptio E [Exception stack trace]
```

I was reading [this article](http://www.cosenonjaviste.it/ejb3-timer-services-il-senso-del-tempo-per-gli-ejb/), it's an italian article, I will translate here the relevant part (the one named "Timer e transazioni"):

> Timer and Transactions
>
> The creation and cancellation of a timer are transactional. This means that if a transaction executes a rollback after the creation or cancellation of a timer, its creation or cancellation aborts. Also, considering that timers are asynchronous, there is no transaction propagation, instead a new transaction gets created (as if it had the REQUIRES_NEW attribute) when the callback method gets called. **If this transaction fails or executes rollback, the container tries to execute it at least one time.**

Now, if I'm understanding it correctly, if the `@Timeout` method fires an execption, the transaction fails and the EJB Container tries to re-call that method.

This is an unwanted behaviour for me, regardless of exceptions I want the `@Timeout` method to be always executed one single time.

> Why don't you use the `@Asynchronous` annotation instead of the `@Timeout`?

Because I'm using Websphere 8, which has a known bug with that annotation. IBM says it is fixed in some of the fixpack they released, but I'm using the latest fixpack and the issue is still there, so this is not an option.

> Why don't you use the `WorkManager` with a `Work` instead?

Because it seems that I must use the work manager implementation class from IBM, and I would like to make my code as much non-server-dependent as possible.

Is there a way to tell the container not to try executing my method again?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you specify `@ConcurrencyManagement` annotation for a stateless bean? This annotation is intended for singleton beans.

Comment: @slwk Good question. I forgot to include the singleton annotation. Actually, this is a sample taken from the code I have, where the `Workflow` class extends a `CommonWorkflow` class, which is a singleton bean. I'm including it.

Answer (score 0):

If your business requirements allow you to change transaction attributes, you could set transaction attribute for `doTask()` method as `REQUIRES_NEW` and then invoke this method through EJB proxy in timeout callback. The idea is following:

```
@Resource
SessionContext sessionContext;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public <T> Future<Object> doTask(T msg) {
  ...
}

@Timeout
private void executeOnTimeout(Timer t) {
    LOG.debug("start -  doTask with timer timeout");
    t.cancel(); //execute one time and cancel the timer
    try {
        WorkflowInterfaceLocal proxy = (WorkflowInterfaceLocal) sessionContext.getBusinessObject(WorkflowInterfaceLocal.class);
        doTask(this.msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
    LOG.debug("end - doTask with timer timeout");
}
```

Comment: As I understood from the article linked in the question, a new transaction gets created by default, what is the difference in creating one manually?

Comment: When you have `doTask()` method with default transaction attribute - `REQUIRED` then it continues transaction that is started in timeout callback. When you get system excpetion then transaction is rolled back and timeout callback is invoked again. However when you invoke `doTask()` with `REQUIRES_NEW` through proxy then in the case of system exception only transaction created for `doTask()` will be rolled back. The transaction associated with timeout callback is different transaction so it won't be marked as rollback and timeout won't be fired again.